# Arduino - serial port interrupt

Tags: serial-port, arduino, interrupt

Arduino question on interrupts:

For my Arduino RTC project I need to put my Arduino to sleep until interrupted by either a [pin interrupt](http://www.geertlangereis.nl/Electronics/Pin_Change_Interrupts/PinChange_en.html) or by a single char present on the serial port (an arbitrary character) -- How may I achieve this?

I see that a pin interrupt is relatively straightforward, but I'm unable complete this by the serial port [I could poll the serial port, but this wastes energy].

Suggestions welcome

Comment: Which Arduino (or more specifically, which MCU)?

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I't the Uno with the Atmel328 MCU   http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf

Comment: Check out this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201590/arduino-serial-interrupts