# Interrupting with SoftwareSerial on Arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupt, software-serial

I'm using Bluetooth serial port profile to communicate with Arduino. The bluetooth module (HC-06) is connected to my digital pins 10 and 11 (RX, TX). The module is working properly, but I need an interrupt on data receive. I can't periodically check for incoming data as Arduino is working on a time-sensitive task (music-playing through a passive buzzer) and I need control signals to interrupt immediately on receive. I've looked through many documents including Arduino's own site, and they all explain how to establish regular communication using checking for `serialPort.available()` periodically. I've found one SO question [Arduino Serial Interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201590/arduino-serial-interrupts) but that's too complicated for my level. Any suggestions on reading realtime input through serial?

Comment: D11 is connected to PCINT3. Go nuts.

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PcInt Do I have to do *everything* for you? :P

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Okay, this would be a good starting point for me.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the current version of SoftSerial actually uses PCINT to detect the individual bits. Hence I believe defining it again at the main loop would conflict with the SoftSerial's actual detection of bits.

I am reluctant to suggest this as it is modifying a core library. Which is difficult not to do when sharing interrupts. But if desperate, you could modify that routine, with your need.

within

```
\arduino-1.5.7\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp.

//
// The receive routine called by the interrupt handler
//
void SoftwareSerial::recv()
{
...
    // if buffer full, set the overflow flag and return
    if ((_receive_buffer_tail + 1) % _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF != _receive_buffer_head) 
    {
      // save new data in buffer: tail points to where byte goes
      _receive_buffer[_receive_buffer_tail] = d; // save new byte
      _receive_buffer_tail = (_receive_buffer_tail + 1) % _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF;
#ifdef YOUR_THING_ENABLE
      // Quickly check if it is what you want and DO YOUR THING HERE!
#endif
    } 
...
}
```

But beware your are still in a ISR and all Interrupts are OFF and you are blocking EVERYTHING. ***One should not lollygag nor dilly dally, here. Do you something quick and get out.***